# Save a xlsx file in a variable, and download by click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax function which returns a xlsx file. But I read that you with ajax can't start the download automatically, for security reasons. So I wanted to save the xlsx file in a variable, and make a button with "ready for download". I were wondering if that's possible.

view function that returns xlsx file.

```
return HttpResponse(save_virtual_workbook(wb), content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
```

javacript

```
var xlsxVar = ''

function ajaxGetCSV() {

    $.ajax({
        url : "{% url 'manager:file' %}", 
        type : "POST", 
        data : { csrfmiddlewaretoken : '{{ csrf_token }}' }, 

        success : function(data) {
            xlsxVar = data
        },

        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(errmsg);
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
};
```

And some click function to begin the download.

Update:

```
<div class='ready'>
    test
</div>

$(".ready").click(function(){
        var link = $("<a></a>");
        link.href = xlsxFile;
        link.download = true;
        link.click();
});
```

The above does still not stat a download.

Comment: That's not possible. However, you can simply use a normal anchor element `<a href="...">` for the download button, and instruct the file to be downloaded by setting the header to an octet-stream.

Comment: The solution of @Terry is the best.

Comment: Is `data` at `success` function a string?

Answer (score 1):

What you have been recommending be done is not possible for security reasons. What you can do is use an anchor tag that links to the file though.

Here is an example where I dynamically create that anchor, and click it

```
var link = $("<a></a>");
link.href = xlsxFile;
link.download = true;
link.click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I've seen the $.create("a") before. I edited my post, can you check if that's the right implementation? I get a '$.create is not a function'

Comment: I've changed the code to match yours, along with changing the method in which the element is created.

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing anything wrong. But it does not appear to be working. The download won't begin. Does it have something to do with the  variable and file?

Comment: `xlsxFile` must be a variable containing the path to the xlsxFile, not the contents of the file.

Comment: @user3880828 `xlsxFile` can be the contents of file if `xlsxFile` is converted to a `data URI` or `Blob URL`